# How shall I get the message in "Sorry, Ubuntu 14.04 has experienced an internal error" in text?

Tags: 14.04

When I start 14.04, I get a dialog, with message of foldable bullets inside. I want to get the message in text, so that I can post it in a question (now I post it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612914/system-problem-and-should-i-uninstall-vivid-kernel-4-0-from-trusty) ). How can I get the message in text? Thanks.[image]

Comment: Typically, I would say you *shouldn't* post it in a question here. Continue with filing a bug.

Comment: @muru:  My problem for the notification is here http://askubuntu.com/questions/612914/system-problem-and-should-i-uninstall-vivid-kernel-4-0-from-trusty.

Answer (score 1):

Well I can tell you how to most likely fix that.
Try running `sudo apt-get remove --purge apport` and then `sudo apt-get install apport` before rebooting.

Comment: Thanks. Why shall I reinstall apport? My problem for the notification is here http://askubuntu.com/questions/612914/system-problem-and-should-i-uninstall-vivid-kernel-4-0-from-trusty.

Comment: That's the cause of the error.

Comment: Why shall I reinstall apport?  what does it fix?

Comment: I had this same problem on Ubuntu. I would have to cancel out at least five error prompts at startup. I looked the problem up and found the suggestion to purge and reinstall `apport` which did get most of the popups away.

Comment: @Tim - Does this answer answer the question, or it helps fixing the problem?